# Reduce a string to a dictionary in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift2

What woudl be a simple way to reduce a string like `AAA:111;BBB:222;333;444;CCC:555` to a dictionary in Swift. I have the following code:

```
var str = "AAA:111;BBB:222;333;444;CCC:555"
var astr = str.componentsSeparatedByString(";").map { (element) -> [String:String] in
    var elements = element.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    if elements.count < 2 {
        elements.insert("N/A", atIndex: 0)
    }
    return [elements[0]:elements[1]]
}
```

The code above produces an **Array** of **Dictionaries**: 
`[["A": "111"], ["BBB": "222"], ["UKW": "333"], ["UKW": "444"], ["CCC": "555"]]`

I want it to produce 
`["A": "111", "BBB": "222", "UKW": "333", "UKW": "444", "CCC": "555"]`
but no mater what I try, since i call the `map` function on an **Array** it seems impossible to convert the nature of the `map` function's result.

NOTE: The dictionary in string format is described as either having `KEY:VALUE;` format or `VALUE;` format, in which case the mapping function will add the `"N/A"` as being the key of the unnamed value.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `map` produces an array of dictionaries. When you want to combine them into 1, that's a perfect job for `reduce`:

```
func + <K,V>(lhs: Dictionary<K,V>, rhs: Dictionary<K,V>) -> Dictionary<K,V> {
    var result = Dictionary<K,V>()

    for (key, value) in lhs {
        result[key] = value
    }
    for (key, value) in rhs {
        result[key] = value
    }

    return result
}

var str = "AAA:111;BBB:222;333;444;CCC:555"
var astr = str
    .componentsSeparatedByString(";")
    .reduce([String: String]()) {
        aggregate, element in
        var elements = element.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
        if elements.count < 2 {
            elements.insert("N/A", atIndex: 0)
        }
        return aggregate + [elements[0]:elements[1]]
    }

print(astr)
```

Swift has no default operator to "combine" two `Dictionaries` so you have to define one. Note that the `+` here is not commutative: `dictA + dictB != dictB + dictA`. If a key exist in both dictionaries, the value from the second dictionary will be used.

Comment: This is okey but you are making it really complicated with that `+` operation. That's not needed at all.

Answer (score 4):

This is a work for `reduce`:

```
let str = "AAA:111;BBB:222;333;444;CCC:555"
let keyValueStrings = str.componentsSeparatedByString(";")
let dictionary = keyValueStrings.reduce([String: String]()) {
    aggregate, element in

    var newAggregate = aggregate

    let elements = element.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    let key = elements[0]

    // replace nil with the value you want to use if there is no value        
    let value = (elements.count > 1) ? elements[1] : nil
    newAggregate[key] = value

    return newAggregate
}

print(dictionary)
```

You can also make `aggregate` mutable directly:

```
let dictionary = keyValueStrings.reduce([String: String]()) {
    (var aggregate: [String: String], element: String) -> [String: String] in

    let elements = element.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    let key = elements[0]

    // replace nil with the value you want to use if there is no value        
    let value = (elements.count > 1) ? elements[1] : nil
    aggregate[key] = value

    return aggregate
}
```

This is a functional approach, but you can achieve the same using a `for` iteration.

Comment: `var` in a param?  Smells like swift 2

Comment: @GitSyncApp Yes, maybe you have missed the "swift2" tag in the question.

Comment: sure. But the internet kinda moved on to swift 3. Also is this the best way to reduce to a dict? Don't you create a new Dict on every iteration? I'm genuinely curious. :)

Comment: @GitSyncApp In the second option with `var` we can be sure that only one dictionary was created. That option is not available in Swift 3. If we are talking about the first option, it all depends on how well is the dictionary implementation optimized. I won't worry about that until I run into an actual performance problem. In general, I would prefer to have a dictionary initializer accepting an array of key-value pairs. Maybe it will come in Swift 4 with the other Dictionary improvements.

Comment: Agree. We came to the same conclusion on swift-lang on slack just now. Here is hoping for swift 4 

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because `map` can only return arrays. If you are using this method to parse your string, then you need to convert it to a dictionary after.

```
var newDict = [String:String]()
for x in astr {
    for (i, j) in x {
        newDict[i] = j
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current issue with your code is that `map` function iterates over array containing `[["key:value"],["key:value"]..]` and you separate it again. But it returns `["key":"value"]` which you then add to your array.

Instead you can add `elements[0]:elements[1]` directly to a locally kept variable which will fix your problem. Something like

`finalVariable[elements[0]] = elements[1]`